# Vue 3 returns an error after running my project and compiling it with npm run dev

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vite

Good day. I tried installing the dependencies of a Vue.JS app repository `npm install`.

Then, I run the Vue.JS app using `npm run dev`. However, after running it, it shows the following error in the terminal:

```
PS G:\malaysia-coronavirus> npm run dev

> malaysia-coronavirus@0.0.0 dev
> vite

node:events:504
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn G:\malaysia-coronavirus\node_modules\esbuild\esbuild.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn G:\\malaysia-coronavirus\\node_modules\\esbuild\\esbuild.exe',
  path: 'G:\\malaysia-coronavirus\\node_modules\\esbuild\\esbuild.exe',
  spawnargs: [ '--service=0.12.15', '--ping' ]
}
```

How do I fix this? Did I do something wrong with the dependencies?

Are there any missing installation that I accidentally skipped?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix it. I just had to simply run:

`node ./node_modules/esbuild/install.js`

Answer from this thread: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1361#issuecomment-754442599